# /W4 for only this project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a project in visual studio. It is reliant upon many other libraries. I want to run warning level 4 when compiling just my code, but exclude/silence any warnings on any code outside of the project. Is there any way to do this in visual studio?

Comment: I seriously doubt it!

Comment: Wrap your #includes for the legacy .h files with #pragma warning(push, 3) and #pragma warning(pop).  Now you can build with /W4 in effect for your own code.